# Lambda type missmatch in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, functional-interface

I am trying to use the lambda operator, I have managed to do similar things with other methods, but this one is giving out an error.

Methods in question:

```
public Icon setOnClick(IconClick e) {
    this.click = e;
    return this;
}
```

and:

```
public interface IconClick {
    boolean onClick(Player p, Icon i, InventoryClickEvent e);
}
```

And here, I tried to use lambda:

```
.setOnClick((Player p, Icon i, InventoryClickEvent e) -> {
        //Code in here
    }));
```

But Eclipse keeps giving this error:

> The method setOnClick(IconClick) in the type Icon is not applicable for the arguments ((Player p, Icon i, InventoryClickEvent e) -> {})

It evens suggest to create a method with arguments IconClick in the Icon class, but that`s method I'm trying to use.

(Using Java 8, compiler compliance level: 1.8 and Eclipse version: 2018-12 (4.10.0))

Comment: Does your porgram compile?

Comment: Eclipse points out an error, it doesn't let me compile it.

Comment: Try compiling it from command line then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just be missing the return type there :

```
IconClick onClick = (Player p, Icon i, InventoryClickEvent e) -> {
     // some logic in here
     return false; // must return 'false' or 'true' 
};

Icon icon = new Icon().setOnClick((p, i, e) -> false); // or 'onClick'
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't fully understood, are you saying that I should add a default return to the method declaration?

Comment: @HunterFP I wanted to say the implementation of lambda that you have should have a `boolean` value returned.